# Dynamic Model Binding Razor Pages

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

I have a Use Case, where I am planning to Use a single Page to Modify  various types of benefit applications submitted by Employees where each application uses different Data Model and separate backend Tables. My plan is to redirect the user from index page to the edit page with ApplicationID and Application Type as parameter. I will retrieve the Record and Generate Dynamic HTML Table (it could possibly done at the Server side or at the Client Side). My Question is -
Is it possible to dynamically bind a model in a Razor Page.  If possible I would love to have some references.
Dynamic model binding will help among other things Model Validation at the Post Handler.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what you want but see if my answer to this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448247/asp-net-core-pages-handler/76449224

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its good solution. However, I have about 15 Different Applications , so I have to add 15 models in my page and have to create 15 partial pages and  minimum 15 Post Handles  I was thinking whether  a more elegant solution is possible.